# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email, exception

I have set up a test email form submission and continue to get the following error message no matter how many ways i try

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at frmQuote.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\firstarPrecision\frmQuote.aspx.cs:line 28

If it is needed here is the C# code that i am using to submit the form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class frmQuote : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text.ToString());
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("swdlodonnell@gmail.com"));
                //message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("copy@domain.com"));
                message.Subject = "Quote request from " + txtCompanyName.Text.ToString();
                message.Body = txtContact.Text.ToString();
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried several ways and it seems to me like i am being blocked by an antivirus/firewall, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a mail server running on the local host?  This has nothing to do with the code.  The mail server (127.0.0.1) isn't allowing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You are triyng to send it through an SMTP on your local machine (127.0.0.1) which I assume does not have an smtp server running.

If you need a facility to send e-mails easily through SMTP I recommend [mandrill smtp](http://mandrill.com/), very easy and free to use,

Comment: This is what happens when you're tired XD. Thanks ill give that mandrill a try, usually i just use a Gmail account as an SMTP server but this is probably a better bet, thanks.

Comment: As I saw your code I supposed you were using gmail, I had a lot of troubles with gmail as smtp (all of them because sending through the same account but from different places, the account got locked each time) so mandrill can help you if you hit the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, as mentioned by others, you need to be running a mail server on localhost for this to work. Port 25 is the default post for SMTP but that doesn't mean there's a mail server standing by. You can use a free e-mail address to make sure the e-mail really gets delivered and the only change you'd need is to add your account credentials (see [this tutorial for reference](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm)). For the port information, check the e-mail provider's instructions for setting up e-mail clients, which should be available in the Settings menu of just about any e-mail provider.

Answer (score 0):

We started seeing this error after upgrading our web server to 2022. We did have the SMTP Server feature installed and running. For us, the solution turned out to have several steps.

1. Our apps had to be upgraded from .Net 4.6 to .Net 4.7.2
2. ALL IIS Manager 6 features needed to be installed... SMTP server still runs on IIS 6 despite having IIS 10 installed on the server as well. The 'internet' has a lot to say about this that I won't go into.
3. Our SMTP server kept throwing this MMC error message when we tried to view the SMTP server properties in IIS Manager 6. We followed the steps here and that error was cleared. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/871780/mmc-has-detected-an-error-in-a-snap-in-it-is-recom
4. We needed to configure SMTP Server to listen on the web server IP and port 25 specifically and not "All Unassigned" in SMTP properties. We did see some posts about changing the port to 600 something. That did not do the trick for us.
5. We needed to add the web server IP to the allowed connection list in SMTP Properties
6. We needed to add the web server IP to the relay list in SMTP properties
7. Update our code to use web server IP and port 25 instead of 127.0.0.1